# Can you make Quartz.Net use a priority queue?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Quart.Net by default only uses the priority of a job if it is triggered at the same time as another job. If two jobs are triggered at different times however, the earliest one will always be run first on the thread pool. I have a scenario though where I need the highest priority job in the queue to always run on the next thread. Is there an easy way to do this with Quartz.Net, or will I have to implement my own scheduler if I wanted this done? (Or move to another technology).

The specific scenario I have in mind:
Periodically jobs will be triggered at a high priority that may produce some output for another process. Minimizing wait times here is reasonably important. However, I also have times where I may trigger batches of up to several thousand jobs at once at a much lower priority. I'm worried that when these "batches" are triggered, that the much more important work will wait too long to run.

Is there an easy way to do this with Quartz.Net or a rival technology?

Comment: Can you feasibly perform the long running operations on separate threads using TPL or BackgroundWorker? I set up a quick test, firing jobs that would block for an extended period and Quartz gave me 4 threads before delaying further jobs, but when wrapping the blocking portion of the Execute method in `Task.Factory.StartNew` my triggers kept firing on time while those threads continued running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Trigger Priorities? I don't think it will run it on a different thread, but it will push the job to start before another job that was triggered before with lower priority.

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
   .WithIdentity("TestTrigger")
   .StartNow()
   .WithPriority(10)
   .Build();
```

Comment: My issue with this is that the priority is only taken into account for jobs that are triggered at the same time. IE, if a job with priority 1 is triggered @ 12:00, and a job with priority 10 @ 12:01, the 12:00 job will always run first. I don't mind this in the sense that if a thread is available it starts then, I'm worried that when I trigger more jobs than threads available at once, I will run into a scenario where high priority jobs do not run for a period (perhaps several minutes).

Comment: Are your jobs all within the one scheduler class?

Comment: Yes. The "batches" of jobs I was referring to was basically the same job running in many different environments (databases). Currently, I have a single JobA<T> where T : IJob that determines all of the places that the job needs to run dynamically, and then schedules a single run of a job detail with different parameters for each one, all on the same scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, this isn't directly supported by Quartz.Net. You could create your own scheduler (see below) or you can work around it if you're using a database store by updating the NEXT_FIRE_TIME column in the QRTZ_TRIGGERS table. If you update the NEXT_FIRE_TIMEs so that they are ordered by the priority, then the next time the scheduler checks for a schedule change, your jobs will be executed in priority order.

There is a

```
public void SignalSchedulingChange(DateTimeOffset? candidateNewNextFireTimeUtc)
```

method on the [QuartzScheduler](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Core/QuartzScheduler.cs) that you could call after updating the fire times but unfortunately it's not exposed by [StdScheduler](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Impl/StdScheduler.cs). If you're going down the "my own scheduler" route, you would call this directly. Otherwise, calling the ScheduleJob method on the scheduler (and scheduling a job) calls this as well, so you could leverage that and schedule a job after updating your next fire times.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this behavior is to subclass `StdAdoDelegate` (or one of the DB specific implementations) and override `GetSelectNextTriggerToAcquireSql` so that it sorts by `PRIORITY` before `NEXT_FIRE_TIME` instead.

The following class fetches the default SQL query and swaps the order by clauses with the help of a temporary null character placeholder:

```
public class CustomAdoDelegate : StdAdoDelegate
{
    protected override string GetSelectNextTriggerToAcquireSql(int maxCount)
    {
        return base.GetSelectNextTriggerToAcquireSql(maxCount)
            .Replace(ColumnNextFireTime + " ASC", "\0")
            .Replace(ColumnPriority + " DESC", ColumnNextFireTime + " ASC")
            .Replace("\0", ColumnPriority + " DESC");
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this could result in long delays for lower priority jobs if the scheduler is overwhelmed with higher priority ones.

I haven't tried it myself but it might be worth considering some kind of hybrid approach that balances the `PRIORITY` and `NEXT_FIRE_TIME` values somehow. For example, you could subtract the priority in seconds from the next fire time to create a kind of variable sized priority window.

```
order by dateadd(ss, -PRIORITY, NEXT_FIRE_TIME)
```

So a priority=10 trigger would only beat a priority=5 trigger if it was triggered no more than 5 seconds later. Just a thought.